# Angular2 - '[object Object]' of module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, firebase

I am having an issue with integrating angularfire2 into my application. I have sorted most issue but I am let with this final one hopefully. I am unsure what the error is but I have pinpointed it to the following code.

This works:

```
//Other imports here
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              HttpModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
              MainModule,
              SharedModule.forRoot()],

  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

But this gives me the error below at the bootstrap property:

```
(SystemJS) Unexpected value '[object Object]' used in the bootstrap property of module 'AppModule'


//Other imports here
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              HttpModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
              MainModule,
              SharedModule.forRoot()],

  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, [
  FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
  defaultFirebase({
    apiKey: 'keyhere',
    authDomain: 'key.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://key.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'key.appspot.com'
  })
]]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its giving you error because you are doing it wrong way and also [Bootstrap](https://angularfire2.com/api/#7-bootstrap) document is not updated for using with modules with latest angular version.

In [Bootstrap](https://angularfire2.com/api/#7-bootstrap) document second parameters are providers of our angular application so in angular latest realesed version we are declaring all our providers inside `@NgModule.providers` so you have to do as follows :

```
//Other imports here
import { FIREBASE_PROVIDERS, defaultFirebase } from 'angularfire2';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              HttpModule,
              RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
              MainModule,
              SharedModule.forRoot()],

  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    defaultFirebase({
      apiKey: 'keyhere',
      authDomain: 'key.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://key.firebaseio.com',
      storageBucket: 'key.appspot.com'
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]    
})

export class AppModule { }
```